# instruct apt package installer to access a different python version

Tags: debian, apt, python

I am using quite an old installation of linux, the system python does not include Python 3.7. I have however installed Python 3.7, as can be seen in the following terminal output, but I would like to instruct the package installer to access that when it tries to run an installation:

```
cardamom@jupiter ~ $ python --version
Python 2.7.12
cardamom@jupiter ~ $ python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.7
cardamom@jupiter ~ $ sudo apt install -y dangerzone
[sudo] Passwort für cardamom: 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 dangerzone : Hängt ab von: python3:any (>= 3.7~)
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
cardamom@jupiter ~ $
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't state which apt-based Linux distribution you're using, I will suppose it's Debian. This should apply for derived distributions, as long as the package `equivs` below exists.

You really should upgrade your system to a recent/supported version, because you'll start having more and more dependency problems.

Anyway, In order to satisfy your dependency problem, you can try and use the package [`equivs`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/equivs):

> [...]
>
> Another use is to circumvent dependency checking: by letting dpkg
>   think a particular package name and version is installed when it
>   isn't, you can work around bugs in other packages' dependencies.
>   (Please do still file such bugs, though.)

You're supposed to create a control file with `equivs-control`:

```
equivs-control python3
```

edit the created file `python3`, for your case you could add or change the relevant lines to:

```
Package: python3
Version: 3.7.7
Architecture: all
```

(and any other field you deem useful, like `Description`)

Then run `equivs-build python3` to create an empty (in this case) package called `python3_3.7.7_all.deb` which you can then install using `dpkg -i python3_3.7.7_all.deb`.

This will satisfy dependencies, but gives no guarantee that you'll have a working result: it depends on what you actually provide with your own python installation. The least you can do is ensure, if it's not already present, that there's also a symlink called `python3`. It might have to be present in `/usr/bin/` rather than only `/usr/local/bin/`.